# Отображение старой версии поста после принятия правки

Tags: предложение, правки, предлагаемые-правки

Кто-то с низкой репутацией правит код. я с такой же низкой репутацией захожу в править, естественно, единственное, что могу сделать - "принять" правку. При этом мне показывают исходный текст, потому что правка не моя, а старшие товарищи еще не добрались  до этого поста :).

Предлагаю показывать исправленный пост не только автору правки, но и тем, кто его "принял"

UPD

попробую сформулировать иначе. Если я правлю чужой пост, и у меня недостаточно рейтинга, SO показывает мне исправленный пост, сообщая, что правка будет видна остальным после проверки. А если передо мной уже сделали правильную правку, то я не могу увидеть исправленный пост до её утверждения, даже если я ее "одобрил"

Comment: а еще там есть пункты. отклонить правку. принять и улучшить, отклонить и править

Comment: наверное, я плохо сформулировал. написал апдейт

Comment: Да, на Meta SE уже было такое предложение (что-то не смог сразу найти). Мне нравится. Суть в том, что до окончательного принятия правки исправленный вариант виден только первоначальному редактору. Часто было бы удобно всем сразу смотреть на этот вариант, т.к. там форматирование лучше.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin♦ вот и я про это же. хотя бы тем кто его поддержал :)